# Getting DNS server, vulnerable to “cache poison” attack

Tags: dns

As a homework at the university, I need to write "cache-poison" exploit, which should add fake "symbolic name <-> IP" mappings to DNS server's cache. So, at first, I need a DNS server which is vulnerable to cache poisoning. What servers (or maybe certain version of server) is vulnerable?

Answer (score 0):

According to [Wikiopedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNS_spoofing) and [this vulnerability matrix](https://kb.isc.org/article/AA-00913/0/BIND-9-Security-Vulnerability-Matrix.html/matrix), BIND takes measures againt these attacks as of version 9.5.0-P1, so you could try an older BIND.

Comment: But what about other DNS servers? I can't find Windows versions for old BIND servers. And it would be better if I could run DNS server without any installations.

Answer (score 0):

Google for "eugene kashpureff dns poisoning".  You're going to need to download and build an old version of BIND 4.x code and use a DNS hacking tool to generate the malicious packets if you have to demonstrate how the attack works.  Good luck.